# Hibernate needed values to save a child

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I currently have working code to save children to a parent entity.  But I'm wondering if I'm doing things right since I now have an overload on select statements going thru hibernate.  I do use caching so atm I don't have delay problems but I'm wondering if I can't be more efficient.  Take this little extract as example

```
MbaLog.debugLog(logger, "Saving CodeType");
Site site = codeType.getSite();
if (site != null && site.isProxy())
    codeType.setSite(siteRepository.loadSiteById(site.getId()));
Long recordId = codeRepository.saveCodeType(codeType);
```

I have an entity CodeType that I'm saving that has a child Site.  This child is passed to the method as a proxy object with just it's id filled in.  Then I fetch a fully loaded Site object from the database and set it on codetype.  Next up I save the codeType with the sessionfactory of hibernate to the database (code not visible here, but it's behind the codeRepository).

This works but I'm loading a full site, that has childs of it's own so I see at least 5 queries passing before the insert.  I could put a lot of stuff lazy on site, but for the time being I rather not do that due to possible code complications in deeper layers.  I had to learn hibernate and JPA on the job and never had much training from experts in the past.  So I'm wondering, is there a shortcut to save the site on codetype ?  Do I need to have it fully loaded or is the id enough ?  or just the id and version (I'm using @version annotation on all my entities for optimistic locking)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Session.get()` (or `EntityManager.find()`) to get a reference to the SIte entity, use `Session.load()` (or `EntityManager.getReference()`) to get this reference.

These methods will return a lazy-loaded proxy on the entity rather than executing a query to get the data of the site.

Comment: Hmmm I'm getting the distinct impression that using my named queries to fetch entities by id isn't the way to go and I should just ask to the sessionfactory => currentsession => load(id) instead of having @NamedQuery(name=Site.QUERY_FIND_BY_ID,query="from Site where id =:" + DomainObject.PARAM_ID) on all my entities ?

Comment: Yes indeed. Such a query is a really bad idea, since it does what Session.get() or EntityManager.find() does natively, except it bypasses the first and the second-level cache, making it much less efficient. Session.get() won't do anything if the entity is already loaded. Your named query will execute the query each time it's called, even if the entity is already loaded.

Comment: thanks for this explaination, especially telling me that it bypasses the first and second level cache. I'll adjust my code accordingly. As I said I learned hibernate on the go with tutorials and extract of articles on the internet. This was very helpfull stuff

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to persist is the relationship between Site and CodeType, a lazy instance is probably enough. So you could use [EntityManager.getReference()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) (lazy load) instead of [EntityManager.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: I see, thing is I don't use the EntityManager, all my hibernate stuff passes by the sessionfactory with named queries.  Query namedQuery = currentSession.getNamedQuery(query);  All my entities have a named query findById on them that I use to load them.

Comment: As @JB Nizet explained, it is probably not the best idea to use this approach.